# Android: How to start an Activity in the background?

Tags: android

Is it possible to start an `Activity` in the background? I need such an `Activity` that can operate in the background and spawn other Activities as needed in response to user commands issued to my Home Screen widget.

Comment: Don't you need a service for this?
An activity is what other frameworks would call a view. It pops up on the screen. If you want to run something in the background it's called a service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to start an Activity in
>   the background?

No.

> I need such an Activity that can
>   operate in the background and spawn
>   other Activities as needed in response
>   to user commands issued to my Home
>   Screen widget.

Your `AppWidgetProvider` can "spawn other Activities as needed in response to user commands issued to my Home Screen widget", assuming that by "user commands" you mean "clicks".